# PrimeFaces icons

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

I cannot find a way to pick the arrow `icons` like the ones present in the `PickList` component, in order to use them in other `CommandButtons`.

Well, I know that in order to use an icon in CommandButton, one has to follow these instructions:

```
<p:commandButton outcome="target" icon="star" title="With Icon"/>
```

having defined the star icon in a css file:

```
.star {
    background-image: url("images/star.png");
}
```

but I would prefer to use exactly the same arrows as for the PickList component.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Primefaces use [jQuery themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) for styling UI. All of the used icons in Primefaces are from there. Just mouseover icon you like (in themeroller) and something like : `.ui-icon-arrow-1-e` will pop. Then use it like this:

```
<p:commandButton action="target" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-e" value="Arrow icon"/>
```

Answer (score 47):

Here a list of all available jQuery UI icons

[jQueryUI Icons Cheatsheet N#1](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html) (click on `Toggle text` to get all the names of the icons)

[jQueryUI Icons Cheatsheet N#2](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/)

at least in `<p:commandLink` you can apply the icons using `styleClass` for example `styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"` (don't remember trying the same on `p:commandButton` - always preferred `<p:commandLink`)

B.T.W , `<p:commandButton` has no `outcome` attribute , `<p:button` has it...

---

**In addition** since PF v5.1.1 you can also use the icons of [**Font Awesome**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) out of the box, by setting to true the `primefaces.FONT_AWESOME` context param , like this

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and using it like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" icon="fa fa-download" type="button"/>
```

or

```
<p:menuitem value="Refresh" url="#" icon="fa fa-refresh"/>
```

See showcase: [PrimeFaces - FontAwesome - Since v5.1.1](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml)

Comment: I am not an expert of JQuery, so I can't tell you why. But I can confirm that ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e is loaded fine in CommandButton, without need of playing with styleClass or css

Comment: yeah, cause in primefaces commandButton you already got the icon attribute , just showed you alternative when using commandLink... + cheatsheet...

Comment: Also check FontAwesome integration which is a great and modern alternative. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me

```
.star {background:url("images/star.png") no-repeat !important;
     width:20px;
     height:16px;
    }
```