# JSF commandLink with image

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have problem with `<p:commandLink>`. I want make hover effect but I can't load image to `<p:graphicImage>` via CSS.

CSS:

```css
.accountEditBtn {
    background-image:
    url('#{request.contextPath}/resources/image/pencil_black.png');
}
```

JSF:

```
<p:commandLink
    update="@form"
    actionListener="#{someBean.someListener}">
    <h:graphicImage styleClass="accountEditBtn" />
</p:commandLink>
```

I see empty rectangle with border.

But when I add alt to graphicImage, I get image over text from alt...

Where my mistake? 
Thank you.
p.s. typing error - classType -> styleClass

Comment: Just a note, but instead of `background-image: url('#{request.contextPath}/resources/image/pencil_black.png');` in CSS you could write `background: url("#{resource['image/pencil_black.png']}");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using styleClass instead of `<h:graphicImage>`

```
<p:commandLink 
   styleClass="accountEditBtn"
   update="@form"
   actionListener="#{someBean.someListener}"/>
```

try this class

```
.accountEditBtn { background-image: url('../resources/image/pencil_black.png'); }
```

B.T.W

isn't is should be images ? or it is image (folder name)

take a look at this as well.. in case you want commandButton with image: [PrimeFaces icons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10152012/617373)

Comment: works... but only when set value="   " + white-space:pre; in css. primefaces 2.2.1.. is it bug or my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use

```
<p:commandButton ... icon="yourbuttonstyleclass"/>
```

and in css

```
.yourbuttonstyleclass {  
background-image: url('../images/yourimage.png') !important;
}
```

Comment: You should refrain from using !important.