# How to remove the border in p:commendlink?

Tags: css, image, jsf, user-interface, primefaces

I have a p:commandLink in xhtml page

```
<p:commandLink onclick="routeDeleteConfirmation.show()" title="Delete">
                    <h:graphicImage class="deleteBinButtonLnk" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{route}" 
                    target="#{routeController.selectedRouteHeader}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Css:

```
.deleteBinButtonLnk {  width: 17px; height: 19px;
                       border-style: none !important;
                       padding: 2px 2px;
                       background: url('../images/buttons/delete_bin_off.png')
                       no-repeat;
}

.deleteBinButtonLnk:hover{ width: 17px; height: 19px;
                           border: none;
                           background: url('../images/buttons/delete_bin_on.png')
                           no-repeat;
```

here it displaying border for the images in h:graphicImage.
i don't need border for it.

please tell a solution.

Comment: Huh? Why do you have as CSS background image on the `<img>` instead of on the `<a>`? This is a totally unexpected and wrong HTML/CSS approach of having an image link.

Comment: I think this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10224573/1692632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got it.

styleClass instead of `<h:graphicImage>`

```
<p:commandLink 
   styleClass="accountEditBtn"
   update="@form"
   actionListener="#{someBean.someListener}"
</p:commandLink>
```

Css class

```
.accountEditBtn { background-image: url('../resources/image/pencil_black.png'); }
```