# How to get jQuery list icon?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

Can I get <kbd>jQuery</kbd> list icon from http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/? Thanks advance!

Comment: please write code what have you tried so far.

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152012/primefaces-icons

Comment: Hi Parth. I mean: suppose, I have a list icon <code>listIcon</code>. And this is my code in [tag:selectOneMenu]
     
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBean.icon}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{managedBean.listIcon}" var="icon"
                   itemLabel="#{icon}" itemValue="#{icon}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: yes should do like that

Comment: Sorry, I can't format code. please answer my question. thanks!!!

Comment: So, How can I do it?

Comment: you have to do like `<p:commandButton action="target" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-e" value="Arrow icon"/>`

Comment: I want to select icon any from list icons for a [tag:menuItem] in menu, not button

Comment: use `<p:menuitem value="Refresh" url="#" icon="fa fa-refresh"/>`

Comment: this may help you http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/fa.xhtml)

```
<h3 style="margin-top:0">Buttons</h3>
<p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="fa fa-fw fa-edit" type="button"/>
<p:commandButton value="Remove" icon="fa fa-fw fa-remove" type="button"/>
<p:commandButton value="Download" icon="fa fa-fw fa-download" type="button"/>

<h3>Menu</h3>
<p:menu>
    <p:submenu label="Document">
        <p:menuitem value="New" url="#" icon="fa fa-plus" />
        <p:menuitem value="Refresh" url="#" icon="fa fa-refresh"/>
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Navigations">
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="fa fa-home"/>
        <p:menuitem value="User" url="#" icon="fa fa-user"/>
    </p:submenu>
</p:menu>
```

Comment: @Thiendoanvan: Please improve the question. It is about jquery and the answer is font-awesome.

Comment: @Kukeltje: It's about jquery, but I changed making of my problem. However, I still want to  exactly answer...